# help with fixing fwts errors log

Tags: acpi, firmware

Here is an extract of results.log:

```
MTRR validation.
Test 1 of 3: Validate the kernel MTRR IOMEM setup.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xc0000000 to 0xdfffffff (PCI Bus 0000:00)
has incorrect attribute Write-Combining.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xfee01000 to 0xffffffff (PCI Bus 0000:00)
has incorrect attribute Write-Protect.
    ====================================================================================================

Test 1 of 1: Kernel log error check.
Kernel message: [ 0.208079] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

ADVICE: This is not exactly a failure mode but a warning from the kernel. The _OSI() method has
implemented a match to the 'Linux' query in the DSDT and this is redundant because the ACPI driver
matches onto the Windows _OSI strings by default.

FAILED [HIGH] KlogACPIErrorMethodExecutionParse: Test 1, HIGH Kernel message: [ 3.512783] ACPI Error
: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DOD] (Node f7425858), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT
(20110623/psparse-536)

ADVICE: This is a bug picked up by the kernel, but as yet, the firmware test suite has no diagnostic
advice for this particular problem.

Found 1 unique errors in kernel log.
   ====================================================================================================


Check if system is using latest microcode.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cannot read microcode file /usr/share/misc/intel-microcode.dat.
Aborted test, initialisation failed.
    ====================================================================================================

MSR register tests.
    FAILED [MEDIUM] MSRCPUsInconsistent: Test 1, MSR SYSENTER_ESP (0x175) has 1 inconsistent values
across 2 CPUs for (shift: 0 mask: 0xffffffffffffffff).
MSR CPU 0 -> 0xf7bb9c40 vs CPU 1 -> 0xf7bc7c40

FAILED [MEDIUM] MSRCPUsInconsistent: Test 1, MSR MISC_ENABLE (0x1a0) has 1 inconsistent values
across 2 CPUs for (shift: 0 mask: 0x400c51889).
MSR CPU 0 -> 0x850088 vs CPU 1 -> 0x850089
   ====================================================================================================

Checks firmware has set PCI Express MaxReadReq to a higher value on non-motherboard devices.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Check firmware settings MaxReadReq for PCI Express devices.
MaxReadReq for pci://00:00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio
Controller (rev 03) is low (128) [Audio device].
MaxReadReq for pci://00:02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh]
Network Connection is low (128) [Network controller].
FAILED [LOW] LowMaxReadReq: Test 1, 2 devices have low MaxReadReq settings. Firmware may have
configured these too low.

ADVICE: The MaxReadRequest size is set too low and will affect performance. It will provide
excellent bus sharing at the cost of bus data transfer rates. Although not a critical issue, it may
be worth considering setting the MaxReadRequest size to 256 or 512 to increase throughput on the PCI
Express bus. Some drivers (for example the Brocade Fibre Channel driver) allow one to override the
firmware settings. Where possible, this BIOS configuration setting is worth increasing it a little
more for better performance at a small reduction of bus sharing.
    ====================================================================================================

PCIe ASPM check.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 2: PCIe ASPM ACPI test.
PCIE ASPM is not controlled by Linux kernel.

ADVICE: BIOS reports that Linux kernel should not modify ASPM settings that BIOS configured. It can
be intentional because hardware vendors identified some capability bugs between the motherboard and
the add-on cards.


Test 2 of 2: PCIe ASPM registers test.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.01h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.01h L1 not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 02h:00h.00h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 02h:00h.00h L1 not enabled.
PASSED: Test 2, PCIE aspm setting matched was matched.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.05h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.05h L1 not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 85h:00h.00h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 85h:00h.00h L1 not enabled.
PASSED: Test 2, PCIE aspm setting matched was matched.

====================================================================================================

Extract and analyse Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).

Test 1 of 2: Check Windows Management Instrumentation in DSDT
Found WMI Method WMAA with GUID: 5FB7F034-2C63-45E9-BE91-3D44E2C707E4, Instance 0x01
Found WMI Event, Notifier ID: 0x80, GUID: 95F24279-4D7B-4334-9387-ACCDC67EF61C, Instance 0x01
PASSED: Test 1, GUID 95F24279-4D7B-4334-9387-ACCDC67EF61C is handled by driver hp-wmi (Vendor: HP).
Found WMI Event, Notifier ID: 0xa0, GUID: 2B814318-4BE8-4707-9D84-A190A859B5D0, Instance 0x01
FAILED [MEDIUM] WMIUnknownGUID: Test 1, GUID 2B814318-4BE8-4707-9D84-A190A859B5D0 is unknown to the
kernel, a driver may need to be implemented for this GUID.

ADVICE: A WMI driver probably needs to be written for this event.
It can checked for using: wmi_has_guid("2B814318-4BE8-4707-9D84-A190A859B5D0").
One can install a notify handler using
wmi_install_notify_handler("2B814318-4BE8-4707-9D84-A190A859B5D0", handler, NULL). 
http://lwn.net/Articles/391230 describes how to write an appropriate driver.

Found WMI Object, Object ID AB, GUID: 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910, Instance 0x01, Flags: 00

Found WMI Method WMBA with GUID: 1F4C91EB-DC5C-460B-951D-C7CB9B4B8D5E, Instance 0x01
Found WMI Object, Object ID BC, GUID: 2D114B49-2DFB-4130-B8FE-4A3C09E75133, Instance 0x7f, Flags: 00

Found WMI Object, Object ID BD, GUID: 988D08E3-68F4-4C35-AF3E-6A1B8106F83C, Instance 0x19, Flags: 00

Found WMI Object, Object ID BE, GUID: 14EA9746-CE1F-4098-A0E0-7045CB4DA745, Instance 0x01, Flags: 00

Found WMI Object, Object ID BF, GUID: 322F2028-0F84-4901-988E-015176049E2D, Instance 0x01, Flags: 00

Found WMI Object, Object ID BG, GUID: 8232DE3D-663D-4327-A8F4-E293ADB9BF05, Instance 0x01, Flags: 00

Found WMI Object, Object ID BH, GUID: 8F1F6436-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A, Instance 0x00, Flags: 00

Found WMI Object, Object ID BI, GUID: 8F1F6435-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A, Instance 0x00, Flags: 00

Found WMI Method WMAC with GUID: 7391A661-223A-47DB-A77A-7BE84C60822D, Instance 0x01
Found WMI Object, Object ID BJ, GUID: DF4E63B6-3BBC-4858-9737-C74F82F821F3, Instance 0x05, Flags: 00
    ====================================================================================================

Disassemble DSDT to check for _OSI("Linux").
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Disassemble DSDT to check for _OSI("Linux").
This is not strictly a failure mode, it just alerts one that this has been defined in the DSDT and
probably should be avoided since the Linux ACPI driver matches onto the Windows _OSI strings
            {
                If (_OSI ("Linux"))
                {
                    Store (0x03E8, OSYS)
                }
                If (_OSI ("Windows 2001"))
                {
                    Store (0x07D1, OSYS)
                }
                If (_OSI ("Windows 2001 SP1"))
                {
                    Store (0x07D1, OSYS)
                }
                If (_OSI ("Windows 2001 SP2"))
                {
                    Store (0x07D2, OSYS)
                }
                If (_OSI ("Windows 2006"))
                {
                    Store (0x07D6, OSYS)
                }
                If (LAnd (MPEN, LEqual (OSYS, 0x07D1)))
                {
                    TRAP (0x01, 0x48)
                }
                TRAP (0x03, 0x35)
            }
WARNING: Test 1, DSDT implements a deprecated _OSI("Linux") test.

====================================================================================================
0 passed, 0 failed, 1 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

ACPI DSDT Method Semantic Tests.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
Failed to install global event handler.
Test 22 of 93: Check _PSR (Power Source).
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 22, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_SB_.AC__._PSR'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.

PASSED: Test 22, \_SB_.AC__._PSR correctly acquired and released locks 16 times.

Test 35 of 93: Check _TMP (Thermal Zone Current Temp).
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 35, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_TZ_.DTSZ._TMP'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.

PASSED: Test 35, \_TZ_.DTSZ._TMP correctly acquired and released locks 14 times.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 35, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_TZ_.CPUZ._TMP'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.

PASSED: Test 35, \_TZ_.CPUZ._TMP correctly acquired and released locks 10 times.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 35, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_TZ_.SKNZ._TMP'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.

PASSED: Test 35, \_TZ_.SKNZ._TMP correctly acquired and released locks 10 times.
PASSED: Test 35, _TMP correctly returned sane looking value 0x00000b4c (289.2 degrees K)
PASSED: Test 35, \_TZ_.BATZ._TMP correctly acquired and released locks 9 times.
PASSED: Test 35, _TMP correctly returned sane looking value 0x00000aac (273.2 degrees K)
PASSED: Test 35, \_TZ_.FDTZ._TMP correctly acquired and released locks 7 times.

Test 46 of 93: Check _DIS (Disable).
FAILED [MEDIUM] MethodShouldReturnNothing: Test 46, \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.SIO_.COM1._DIS returned values,
but was expected to return nothing.
Object returned:
  INTEGER: 0x00000000

ADVICE: This probably won't cause any errors, but it should be fixed as the AML code is not
conforming to the expected behaviour as described in the ACPI specification.

FAILED [MEDIUM] MethodShouldReturnNothing: Test 46, \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.SIO_.LPT0._DIS returned values,
but was expected to return nothing.
Object returned:
  INTEGER: 0x00000000

ADVICE: This probably won't cause any errors, but it should be fixed as the AML code is not
conforming to the expected behaviour as described in the ACPI specification.


Test 61 of 93: Check _WAK (System Wake).
Test _WAK(1) System Wake, State S1.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 61, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_WAK'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.

Test _WAK(2) System Wake, State S2.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 61, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_WAK'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.


Test _WAK(3) System Wake, State S3.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 61, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_WAK'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.


Test _WAK(4) System Wake, State S4.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 61, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_WAK'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.


Test _WAK(5) System Wake, State S5.
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP during execution of method COMP
WARNING: Test 61, Detected an infinite loop when evaluating method '\_WAK'. 

ADVICE: This may occur because we are emulating the execution in this test environment and cannot
handshake with the embedded controller or jump to the BIOS via SMIs. However, the fact that AML code
spins forever means that lockup conditions are not being checked for in the AML bytecode.




Test 87 of 93: Check _BCL (Query List of Brightness Control Levels Supported).
  Package has 2 elements:
    00: INTEGER: 0x00000000
    01: INTEGER: 0x00000000
FAILED [MEDIUM] Method_BCLElementCount: Test 87, Method _BCL should return a package of more than 2
integers, got just 2.


Test 88 of 93: Check _BCM (Set Brightness Level).
ACPICA Exception AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT during execution of method _BCM
FAILED [CRITICAL] AEAMLPackgeLimit: Test 88, Detected error 'Package limit' when evaluating
'\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCM'.

====================================================================================================


ACPI table settings sanity checks.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Check ACPI tables.
PASSED: Test 1, Table APIC passed.
Table ECDT not present to check.
FAILED [MEDIUM] FADT32And64BothDefined: Test 1, FADT 32 bit FIRMWARE_CONTROL is non-zero, and
X_FIRMWARE_CONTROL is also non-zero. Section 5.2.9 of the ACPI specification states that if the
FIRMWARE_CONTROL is non-zero then X_FIRMWARE_CONTROL must be set to zero.

ADVICE: The FADT FIRMWARE_CTRL is a 32 bit pointer that points to the physical memory address of the
Firmware ACPI Control Structure (FACS). There is also an extended 64 bit version of this, the
X_FIRMWARE_CTRL pointer that also can point to the FACS. Section 5.2.9 of the ACPI specification
states that if the X_FIRMWARE_CTRL field contains a non zero value then the FIRMWARE_CTRL field
*must* be zero. This error is also detected by the Linux kernel. If FIRMWARE_CTRL and
X_FIRMWARE_CTRL are defined, then the kernel just uses the 64 bit version of the pointer.

PASSED: Test 1, Table HPET passed.
PASSED: Test 1, Table MCFG passed.
PASSED: Test 1, Table RSDT passed.
PASSED: Test 1, Table RSDP passed.
Table SBST not present to check.
PASSED: Test 1, Table XSDT passed.

    ====================================================================================================

Re-assemble DSDT and find syntax errors and warnings.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 2: Disassemble and reassemble DSDT
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError4043: Test 1, Assembler error in line 2261
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
02258|                     0x00000000,         // Range Minimum
02259|                     0xFEDFFFFF,         // Range Maximum
02260|                     0x00000000,         // Translation Offset
02261|                     0x00000000,         // Length
     |                              ^
     | error 4043: Invalid combination of Length and Min/Max fixed flags
02262|                     ,, _Y0E, AddressRangeMemory, TypeStatic)
02263|                 DWordMemory (ResourceProducer, PosDecode, MinFixed, MaxFixed, Cacheable, ReadWrite,
02264|                     0x00000000,         // Granularity
====================================================================================================

ADVICE: (for error #4043): This occurs if the length is zero and just one of the resource MIF/MAF
flags are set, or the length is non-zero and resource MIF/MAF flags are both set. These are illegal
combinations and need to be fixed. See section 6.4.3.5 Address Space Resource Descriptors of version
4.0a of the ACPI specification for more details.

FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError4050: Test 1, Assembler error in line 2268
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
02265|                     0xFEE01000,         // Range Minimum
02266|                     0xFFFFFFFF,         // Range Maximum
02267|                     0x00000000,         // Translation Offset
02268|                     0x011FEFFF,         // Length
     |                              ^
     | error 4050: Length is not equal to fixed Min/Max window  
02269|                     ,, , AddressRangeMemory, TypeStatic)
02270|             })
02271|             Method (_CRS, 0, Serialized)
====================================================================================================

ADVICE: (for error #4050): The minimum address is greater than the maximum address. This is illegal.

FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1104: Test 1, Assembler error in line 8885
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
08882|                         Method (_DIS, 0, NotSerialized)
08883|                         {
08884|                             DSOD (0x02)
08885|                             Return (0x00)
     |                                        ^
     | warning level 0 1104: Reserved method should not return a value    (_DIS)
08886|                         }
08887| 
08888|                         Method (_SRS, 1, NotSerialized)
====================================================================================================
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1104: Test 1, Assembler error in line 9195
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09192|                         Method (_DIS, 0, NotSerialized)
09193|                         {
09194|                             DSOD (0x01)
09195|                             Return (0x00)
     |                                        ^
     | warning level 0 1104: Reserved method should not return a value    (_DIS)
09196|                         }
09197| 
09198|                         Method (_SRS, 1, NotSerialized)
====================================================================================================
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1127: Test 1, Assembler error in line 9242
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09239|                             CreateWordField (CRES, \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.SIO.LPT0._CRS._Y21._MAX, MAX2)
09240|                             CreateByteField (CRES, \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.SIO.LPT0._CRS._Y21._LEN, LEN2)
09241|                             CreateWordField (CRES, \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.SIO.LPT0._CRS._Y22._INT, IRQ0)
09242|                             CreateWordField (CRES, \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.SIO.LPT0._CRS._Y23._DMA, DMA0)
     |                                                                                         ^
     | warning level 0 1127: ResourceTag smaller than Field    (Tag: 8 bits, Field: 16 bits)
09243|                             If (RLPD)
09244|                             {
09245|                                 Store (0x00, Local0)
====================================================================================================
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1128: Test 1, Assembler error in line 18682
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18679|                     Store (0x01, Index (DerefOf (Index (Local0, 0x02)), 0x01))
18680|                     If (And (WDPE, 0x40))
18681|                     {
18682|                         Wait (\_SB.BEVT, 0x10)
     |                                             ^
     | warning level 0 1128: Result is not used, possible operator timeout will be missed
18683|                     }
18684| 
18685|                     Store (BRID, Index (DerefOf (Index (Local0, 0x02)), 0x02))
====================================================================================================

ADVICE: (for warning level 0 #1128): The operation can possibly timeout, and hence the return value
indicates an timeout error. However, because the return value is not checked this very probably
indicates that the code is buggy. A possible scenario is that a mutex times out and the code
attempts to access data in a critical region when it should not. This will lead to undefined
behaviour. This should be fixed.

Table DSDT (0) reassembly: Found 2 errors, 4 warnings.

Test 2 of 2: Disassemble and reassemble SSDT
PASSED: Test 2, SSDT (0) reassembly, Found 0 errors, 0 warnings.
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1104: Test 2, Assembler error in line 60
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00057|         {
00058|             Store (CPDC (Arg0), Local0)
00059|             GCAP (Local0)
00060|             Return (Local0)
     |                          ^
     | warning level 0 1104: Reserved method should not return a value (_PDC)
00061|         }
00062| 
00063|         Method (_OSC, 4, NotSerialized)
====================================================================================================
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1104: Test 2, Assembler error in line 174
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00171|         {
00172|             Store (\_PR.CPU0.CPDC (Arg0), Local0)
00173|             GCAP (Local0)
00174|             Return (Local0)
     |                          ^
     | warning level 0 1104: Reserved method should not return a value (_PDC)
00175|         }
00176| 
00177|         Method (_OSC, 4, NotSerialized)
====================================================================================================
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1104: Test 2, Assembler error in line 244
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00241|         {
00242|             Store (\_PR.CPU0.CPDC (Arg0), Local0)
00243|             GCAP (Local0)
00244|             Return (Local0)
     |                          ^
     | warning level 0 1104: Reserved method should not return a value (_PDC)
00245|         }
00246| 
00247|         Method (_OSC, 4, NotSerialized)
====================================================================================================
FAILED [HIGH] AMLAssemblerError1104: Test 2, Assembler error in line 290
Line | AML source
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00287|         {
00288|             Store (\_PR.CPU0.CPDC (Arg0), Local0)
00289|             GCAP (Local0)
00290|             Return (Local0)
     |                          ^
     | warning level 0 1104: Reserved method should not return a value (_PDC)
00291|         }
00292| 
00293|         Method (_OSC, 4, NotSerialized)
====================================================================================================
Table SSDT (1) reassembly: Found 0 errors, 4 warnings.
PASSED: Test 2, SSDT (2) reassembly, Found 0 errors, 0 warnings.
PASSED: Test 2, SSDT (3) reassembly, Found 0 errors, 0 warnings.

====================================================================================================
3 passed, 10 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

Critical failures: 1
 method test, at 1 log line: 1449: Detected error 'Package limit' when evaluating '\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCM'.

High failures: 11
 klog test, at 1 log line: 121: HIGH Kernel message: [    3.512783] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DOD] (Node f7425858), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20110623/psparse-536)
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1668: Assembler error in line 2261
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1687: Assembler error in line 2268
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1703: Assembler error in line 8885
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1716: Assembler error in line 9195
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1729: Assembler error in line 9242
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1742: Assembler error in line 18682
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1766: Assembler error in line 60
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1779: Assembler error in line 174
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1792: Assembler error in line 244
 syntaxcheck test, at 1 log line: 1805: Assembler error in line 290

Medium failures: 9
 mtrr test, at 1 log line: 76: Memory range 0xc0000000 to 0xdfffffff (PCI Bus 0000:00) has incorrect attribute Write-Combining.
 mtrr test, at 1 log line: 78: Memory range 0xfee01000 to 0xffffffff (PCI Bus 0000:00) has incorrect attribute Write-Protect.
 msr test, at 1 log line: 165: MSR SYSENTER_ESP (0x175) has 1 inconsistent values across 2 CPUs for (shift: 0 mask: 0xffffffffffffffff).
 msr test, at 1 log line: 173: MSR MISC_ENABLE (0x1a0) has 1 inconsistent values across 2 CPUs for (shift: 0 mask: 0x400c51889).
 wmi test, at 1 log line: 528: GUID 2B814318-4BE8-4707-9D84-A190A859B5D0 is unknown to the kernel, a driver may need to be implemented for this GUID.
 method test, at 1 log line: 1002: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.SIO_.COM1._DIS returned values, but was expected to return nothing.
 method test, at 1 log line: 1011: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.SIO_.LPT0._DIS returned values, but was expected to return nothing.
 method test, at 1 log line: 1443: Method _BCL should return a package of more than 2 integers, got just 2.
 acpitables test, at 1 log line: 1643: FADT 32 bit FIRMWARE_CONTROL is non-zero, and X_FIRMWARE_CONTROL is also non-zero. Se
```

Comment: In most cases, the issues pointed out by this test suite require BIOS changes to fix.  You could check to see if your vendor has provided any BIOS updates, but in general this seems off topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these won't affect the behavior of your system in a negative way. The kernel does try to workaround problematic firmware but usually to get these kind of issues fixed one has to pester the BIOS vendor to fix this issues.

Best to refer to the `fwts` [reference wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/fwts).